# How to use routing inside mat tabs?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have read the documentation of angular material on `mat-tabs`. 
The basic concept of mat-tabs is very easy to understand but the concept where the routing is used inside the mat tabs is some what confusing.

Here's the example that is provided for using routing inside the mat-tabs which is done by using `<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>`

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>


 <a mat-tab-link
 *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
 [routerLink]="link.path"
 routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
 [active]="rla.isActive">
{{link.label}}
  </a>
</nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I understood all the properties in this example except the routerLinkActive  property and the rla.isActive value which is given to active property

Can anyone make this concept clear

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

`routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"` checks the current link which is active in bar whereas `rla.isActive` sets underline on the tab which routed.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the full example I have in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-tabs-router)